# Joined / Connected Dynamic Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Greetings Stackoverflow Veterans,

I've been struggling for a little while with a small Input Safety Feature. Essentially, for my website users will get to pick a time they wish to start and end their morning shift.

I have two `Select` inputs which are populated by a `date` within a loop. Basically, what I've been trying (In vain) to achieve is that when someone picks a start date from the "Start Time" Dropdown, the "End Time" dropdown then has all values less than the "Start Time", disabled.

I've provided an image below to help explain a little better, and the current code I have as well in relation to how my `select` is working.

As for any progress on Javascript, there basically is none. Everything I have tried in no way works, and I'm starting to struggle to think of new ideas. I've spent plenty of time trying to find solutions here on StackOverflow but I might be searching with the wrong Keywords.

[The start time has been selected on the Left Dropdown, at 07:00, but on the Right Dropdown, anything before 07:00 should now be removed / disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFI2g.png)

```
<select id="mondayWorking_MorningStart" class="workInput" >
  <?php 
    $tStart = strtotime($start); 
    $tEnd = strtotime($end); 
    $tNow = $tStart;

    while($tNow <= $tEnd)
    {
      echo "<option id='monday_MorningStart' name='mondayMorningStart'>" . date("H:i",$tNow) . "</option>"; 
      $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Thank you for your help,

If you need anything else to offer your help, please let me know!

Comment: Will [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehsant/L1q8dmp6/) help you?

Comment: @alec-hyve-weekes You are welcome, then I'll post an answer for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the second dropdown based on first drop down value, first you have to bind `onChange` event to first dropdown. It means that when you change the first dropdown and select another option, JavaScript(In our case jquery) will fire an event and run a code.

In that function(code) we get the value of the first dropdown, then clear the options of the second dropdown and refill the content of the second dropdown based on the first dropdown value.

I assumed that the second dropdown max value can be 24:00 and the min value should be equal to first dropdown value + 30 minutes...

I've just added a few options to first select for test. you are loading it with your php code and it makes no difference...

So the code will be like this:

```js
$('#selStart').change(function(){
  var arrTimeStart = $(this).val().split(":");
  var timeStart = parseInt(arrTimeStart[0] * 60) + parseInt(arrTimeStart[1]);
  timeStart = timeStart + 30;
  var timeEnd = (24 * 60);
  
  $('#selEnd').find('option').remove();
  for (iCnt = timeStart; iCnt <= timeEnd; iCnt = iCnt + 30){
    vHour = parseInt(iCnt / 60);
    vMin = iCnt % 60;
    if(vMin == 0)
      vMin = '00';
    tmpTime = vHour + ':' + vMin;
    $('#selEnd').append('<option value='+tmpTime+'>'+tmpTime+'</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start:
<select id="selStart">
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
  <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
  <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
  <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
  <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
  <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
  <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
  <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
</select>
<br>
End:
<select id="selEnd"></select>
```